# SSIS 2012 - Package Task Run Time Status

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

In Table [catalog].[execution_component_phases] there is an column called as
Phase. The Value of the Phase Column are:

- PreExecute
- Validate
- ProcessInput
- ReleaseConnection
- AcquireConnection.

Can someone please suggest which value is saying specific Task in a
package is in Running Status.

Is there any value which states task is started but not completed yet.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the official documentation of `[catalog].[execution_component_phases]` table:

> Displays the time spent by a data flow component in each execution phase.
>
> This view displays a row for each execution phase of a data flow component, such as Validate, Pre-Execute, Post-Execute, PrimeOutput, and ProcessInput. Each row displays the start and end time for a specific execution phase.

Based on my experience i can assume that the Order of the execution phases is:

1. AcquireConnection : Acquiring the related connections required
2. Validate :  *Validating the Task/Component*
3. Pre-Execute
4. ProcessInput : *Processing phase*
5. PrimeOutput : *Generating outputs*
6. Post-Execute
7. ReleaseConnection : *Release acquired connections*

In the official documentation they provided the following query to read the time spent in each phase:

```
use SSISDB  
select package_name, task_name, subcomponent_name, execution_path,  
    SUM(DATEDIFF(ms,start_time,end_time)) as active_time,  
    DATEDIFF(ms,min(start_time), max(end_time)) as total_time  
from catalog.execution_component_phases  
where execution_id = 1841  
group by package_name, task_name, subcomponent_name, execution_path  
order by package_name, task_name, subcomponent_name, execution_path
```

Based on the information above, you can - as example - check whether the current task phase to know if it is still running or not.

**References**

- [catalog.execution_component_phases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-execution-component-phases?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks, so if task is still running the end time be NULL right ? Please suggest

Comment: @TULSI yes, end_time is The time when the phase ended